# mod $p$ homology module of unordered configuration spaces of the projective plane

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology, configuration-spaces

Let $M$ be a manifold and $k$ be a positive integer. Let $F(M,k)$ be the $k$-th ordered configuration space  over $M$, consisting of all ordered $k$-tuples of distinct points in $M$. Let $\Sigma_k$ be the symmetric group on $k$-letters. Let $F(M,k)/\Sigma_k$ be the $k$-th unordered configuration space  over $M$, consisting of all unordered $k$-tuples of distinct points in $M$.

**Question 1:** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Are there any references/results about the homology module
$$
H_*(F(\mathbb{R}P^2,p)/\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_p)?
$$

**My attempt:** I search online and find that in the paper [ON THE HOMOLOGY OF CONFIGURATION SPACES, C.F. Bodigheimer, F. Cohen and L. Taylor, 1989](http://www3.nd.edu/~taylor/papers/cocs.pdf) Theorem C, we can obtain  the homology module
$$
H_*(F(\mathbb{R}P^2,p)/\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_p(-1))
$$
 of the chain complex 
$$
S_*(F(\mathbb{R}P^2,p))\otimes _{\Sigma_p}\mathbb{Z}_p(-1)
$$
where $S_*$ is the singular chain complex and  $\mathbb{Z}_p(-1)$ is the $\Sigma_p$-module $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\Sigma_p$-action given by $$\pi(1)=(-1)^{\text{sign}(\pi)}$$
for any $\pi\in\Sigma_p$.

**Question 2:** If $$
H_j(F(\mathbb{R}P^2,p)/\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_p(-1))=0,
$$
can we conclude
 $$
H_j(F(\mathbb{R}P^2,p)/\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_p )=0?
$$